# What trouble will I get into if I use a headphone jack for serial communication between two arduinos?

Tags: arduino, serial, communication, plug, stereo

I have a project that requires two arduinos to exchange some information when connected together via wire. When the connection is made, Arduino A should start sending a message. When Arduino B has received the complete message, it should send back a certain signal.

For esthetic reasons, the connection needs to be a 3.5mm headphone jack and corresponding plug stereo plug with a ring, tip and sleeve.

My plan is to use SoftwareSerial and have each Arduino write to/read from two digital pins. I'm planning to connect the ground for both Arduinos to the headphone sleeve, connect Arduino A's output pin/Arduino B's input pin to the tip, and Arduino A's input pin/Arduino B's output pin to the ring. The jack is connected to Arduino A, the plug is connected to Arduino B.

The headphone jack has the following pinout:

[image: headphone jack pinout]

Pin 1 is connected to the sleeve, pin 5 to the tip (and therefore Arduino A's output pin), and pin 2 to the ring (and therefore Arduino A's input pin). To allow for connection detection, I'm thinking of connecting pin 4 to ground and setting pin 5 (connected to the softwareserial output pin) to INPUT_HIGH, using the internal resistor to pull the pin high when nothing is connected.

When no plug is inserted, the jack's pin 5 is connected to 4 and therefore pulled LOW. On every iteration I'll read the value of the output pin and as long as it is low, I do nothing.

When a plug is plugged in, the jack's pin 5 gets disconnected from pin 4, and because of the pullup resistor gets pulled HIGH. If I detect that in my loop, I can start sending the first message over the output pin and start listening for a response on the input pin. When I receive a response (or pin 5 gets pulled LOW again when the plug is removed).

I know it's not ideal but for this situation it works. I'm just wondering what unforeseen issues I might run into, especially since I use both pinMode(txPin, INPUT_PULLUP) and SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin) on the same pin, essentially using txPin for both input and output.

Comment: If all that needed is detecting the connection and half-duplex communication, then one ground and one signal pin would be sufficient.

Comment: I'd suggest that you connect pin-3 to ground instead to use the RX pin-2 as your connection detection line. The default state for a serial UART (even a software UART) is 'high', so when you plug both ends of the cable in pin-2 would switch from low to high. Doing it this way eliminates the risk that you might try to transmit into a grounded pin.

Comment: @jay can't do that, because I don't know when to start listening to Arduino B, because I don't know when it has received the message. I have to keep sending it until Arduino B sends a response, so I need full duplex communication.

Comment: @brhans that's a very good idea, I wasn't aware of the default HIGH state. Thanks! I'm wondering if I should switch the pins around though: rx is on pin 5 and tx on pin 2. That way, the plug has to be inserted all the way in before a connection is detected.

Is there a risk on setting rx to both INPUT_PULLUP and as the receiving pin on SoftwareSerial?

Comment: @Bas I agree. It takes what it takes, Just the cost/work (hw/sw) moves from one side to another, which could be matter of the logical vs physical media, protocol stack, speed, application, etc. What is the speed/application of the link? Fast, a lot of data?

Comment: @jay all it has to do is transmit an at most six digit number to the other arduino, and the other arduino has to send it back once to indicate that it received the message. It’s very simple and more than fast enough for this application. Thanks for your input!